# How to change position of current location button on Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I change the position of the current location button in Google Map on Android. I'm using Android studio and Google API version 2.
this button is located on up-right. I want to be on bottom-left.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where is it? Where do you want it? What have you done so far?

Comment: What do you mean when you say change? Change the location of marker or? If you change the position of your phone then just run some update to change the position of marker on maps is this what you want?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785542/how-to-change-the-position-of-my-location-button-in-google-maps-using-android-st][1]
refer this link