# How to change the position of My Location Button in Google Maps using android studio

Tags: java, android, html, google-maps, android-studio

I am working on google maps, and I need to change position of My Location(current location button). Presently current location button is at top-right side. So please help me how to re-position the current location button on google maps screen. Thanks in advance.

my sample code:

```
final GoogleMap googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I don't think is possible.

Comment: better code format and fixed some grammatical format

Comment: The only way, setPadding() from the docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding

Comment: There is a feature request entry in Google Public Issue Tracker to change the properties of my location button: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829640

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can use this

```
View locationButton = ((View) mMapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
// position on right bottom
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rlp.setMargins(0, 180, 180, 0);
```

Comment: for further details check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591524/android-align-left-aligns-to-the-center

Comment: here actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688470/android-google-maps-api-change-position-of-maps-toolbar/31337222#31337222   and Yashwanth has mistake in double ALIGN-PARENT_TOP

Comment: how to perform self click on it ? locationButton.performClick() is not working anymore..

Answer (score 31):

I solved this problem in my map fragment by re positioning my location button to the right bottom corner of view using code below, here is my 
MapsActivity.java :-

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    View mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (mapView != null &&
                mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            // Get the button view
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is layout of fragment :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.infogird.www.location_button_reposition.MapFragment">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope, this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this realign to? layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

Comment: @KaranThakkar bottom-end with 30px gap from bottom and end

Comment: how to perform self click on it ? locationButton.performClick() is not working anymore..

Answer (score 15):

Kotlin version of accepted answer (for bottom-right) (because autoconvert fails with this code)

```
 val locationButton= (mapView.findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("1")).parent as View).findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("2"))
 val rlp=locationButton.layoutParams as (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
 // position on right bottom
 rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0)
 rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE)
 rlp.setMargins(0,0,30,30);
```

Comment: how to perform self click on it ? locationButton.performClick() is not working anymore..

Answer (score 11):

You can use below code for all conditions such as:
1.If you want show location button in top-right
2.If you want show location button in bottom-right
3.If you want show location button in bottom-left

1.If you want to show location button in top-right

```
View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

2.If you want show location button in bottom-right

```
 View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);rlp.setMargins(0,0,30,30);
```

3.If you want show location button in bottom-left

```
 View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            // position on right bottom


            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);

             rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, 0);
            rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            rlp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 40);
```

Best of Luck

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin Version for MapFragment of Accepted Answer

```
val locationButton = (mapFragment.view?.findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("1"))?.parent as View).findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("2"))
                    val rlp =  locationButton.getLayoutParams() as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
                    rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Building on top of the above response and if anyone is looking to use a custom location icon, here is a how I have done it:  ```val locationButton = (mapFragment?.view?.findViewById<View> (Integer.parseInt("1"))?.parent as View)
                                                .findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("2")) as 
     ImageView
        locationButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_location_button)```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's been answered and accepted but these answers didn't work for me.  Perhaps there have been changes in the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or even in GoogleMaps since it was answered.

In my attempts with the existing answers I realized that there may be more LayoutParam rules for the compass button that are overriding my attempts to move the compass button where I wanted it.  I experimented by removing several params like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                locationButton.getLayoutParams();

layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
```

And then adding the new rules as they did in several of the answers.  But it still did not work as expected.  More often than not, the button stayed somewhere on the left side.

I decided to just create new LayoutParams and replace the existing ones and ... it worked perfectly!

I originally used the view tag for `GoogleMapCompass`, but the question pertained to the `GoogleMapMyLocationButton`. So I commented out the `GoogleMapCompass` line and put in the `GoogleMapMyLocationButton` line.

Here is the code for MapFragment.java:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment = null;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()");

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");

        View mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        moveCompassButton(mapView);
    }

    /**
     * Move the compass button to the right side, centered vertically.
     */
    public void moveCompassButton(View mapView) {
        try {
            assert mapView != null; // skip this if the mapView has not been set yet

            Log.d(TAG, "moveCompassButton()");

            // View view = mapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapCompass");
            View view = mapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");

            // move the compass button to the right side, centered
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            layoutParams.setMarginEnd(18);

            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "moveCompassButton() - failed: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By setting padding to GoogleMap Fragment you can change position of **myLocationButton** but only problem is that it will also change positions of other buttons like zoom .

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {  
    map.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in `onCreate` method after the `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)`. It will place your **My Location** button in bottom right.

```
View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can only set padding, like so:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   googleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
   ...
}
```

I ended up creating my own and embedding it in a frame layout using `layout_gravity` to specify where I want it, in this case bottom/end:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="300dp">

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       .../>


     <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/myLocationCustomButton"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_my_location_button_size"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_my_location_button_size"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:background="@drawable/disc"
       android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
       android:padding="@dimen/margin_smallest"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location"
       ../>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, in the activity, I initialized and started a google api client which I can use to fetch current location when needed by the button during a click, see the button click listener below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    myLocationButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myLocationCustomButton);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    myLocationButton.performClick();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    myLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16);
            MainActivity.this.googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 250, null);
        }
    });
```

My app sub-module's `build.gradle` also has:

```
ext {
    playServicesVersion = "8.4.0"
}

dependencies {
   ...     
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Its work display My Location Button Bottom Right Corner on MapView

> XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> JAVA

```
private MapView mMapView;

mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap mMap) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        if (mMapView != null && mMapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
            View locationButton = ((View) mMapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 20);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. You disable the default "My Location" button and make a  custom button at position of your wish and on the click of that button you move camara to current latlng.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

`var locationButton =mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton")`

Java

`View locationButton =mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton")`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to **move the location button** because I was viewing the Google Map in immersive / fullscreen mode and having the app theme's DisplayCutoutMode set to `shortEdges`:

```
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

As a result, the camera display cutout of a Galaxy s10 blocked the view of the current location button since the in-display camera was in the top-right of the screen. You may also want to do this if you have the map display under the statusbar. In these cases, we need the location button to fitSystemWindow. Here's some Kotlin code I added right after I set `googleMap.isMyLocationEnabled` to `true`..

1. **Get a reference** to the button:

   ```
    val locationButton: View? = fragmentContainerView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton")
   ```
2. **Apply any changes** you need to the button. In my case, I want the button to fit the system window:

   ```
    locationButton?.fitsSystemWindows = true
   ```

Answer (score 0):

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
this.googleMap = googleMap;

```
    //        get location current location and customization of current location button
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setPadding(0, 130, 18, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        // get location current location and customization of current location button
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated the Google libraries, use only this method

```
View myLocationButton = mMap.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myLocationButton.getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```