# How to change the location button of the google maps to the bottom left just above the Google Maps Icon when using android Map Support Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I am using Google Maps in fragment using Google Support Map Fragment to replace the parent fragment container with the Maps. Below is my code..

In my Fragment Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.--.--.--.fragments.LocationFragment">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/locationFragMapContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

and then in my Fragment OnCreateView()

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location,container,false);

    /**
     * Get the Child fragment and replace it in the parent fragment container
     */
    mSupportMapFragment = CustomChildMapFragment.newInstance();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.locationFragMapContainer,mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    return view;
}
```

[One Solution to change location button from top to bottom can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785542/how-to-change-the-position-of-my-location-button-in-google-maps-using-android-st) but I want to change the location button to the left bottom just above the Google Icon on the Maps.

```
  // Align it to - parent BOTTOM|LEFT
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
```

I got the above solution from [Github GIST](https://gist.github.com/bdiegel/3107218187008ca9a05e) but it doesn't seem to work out.

Is Google trying to enforce to stop bad people from overriding their Brand Logo ? Or am I doing something wrong here ?

I have no intention to override or replace Google Logo it is just the requirement that I have. I will be keeping the button above the Logo complying to guidelines